# Xamarin iOS in Visual Studio -- debugging statements are logged twice

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2013

In iOS front end, code, if I call

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello!");
```

I see the following in the Visual Studio output window:

```
2013-12-17 13:46:25.319 GraCalcIOS[10241:a0b] Hello!
[0:] Hello!
[0:]
```

I would greatly prefer to see just the following:

```
Hello!
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's already a bug filed about this:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13924

You can CC yourself on the bug to be notified when it's fixed.